# Why are Scala for loops so much faster than while loops for processing a sequence of distinct objects?

Tags: performance, scala

I recently read a post about for loops over a range of integers being slower than the corresponding while loops, which is true, but wanted to see if the same held up for iterating over existing sequences and was surprised to find the complete opposite by a large margin.

First and foremost, I'm using the following function for timing:

```
def time[A](f: => A) = {
    val s = System.nanoTime
    val ret = f
    println("time: " + (System.nanoTime - s) / 1e6 + "ms")
    ret
}
```

and I'm using a simple sequence of Integers:

```
val seq = List.range(0, 10000)
```

(I also tried creating this sequence a few other ways in case the way this sequence was accessed affected the run time. Using the `Range` type certainly did. This should ensure that each item in the sequence is an independent object.)

I ran the following:

```
time {
  for(item <- seq) {
    println(item)
  }
}
```

and

```
time {
  var i = 0
  while(i < seq.size) {
    println(seq(i))
    i += 1
  }
}
```

I printed the results so to ensure that we're actually accessing the values in both loops. The first code snippet runs in an average of **33 ms** on my machine. The second takes an average of **305 ms**.

I tried adding the mutable variable `i` to the for loop, but it only adds a few milliseconds. The `map` function gets similar performance to a for loop, as expected. For whatever reason, this doesn't seem to occur if I use an array (converting the above defined `seq` with `seq.toArray`). In such a case, the for loop takes 90 ms and the while loop takes 40 ms.

What is the reason for this major performance difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is: complexity. `seq(i)` is Θ(i) for `List`, which means your whole loop takes quadratic time. The `foreach` method, however, is linear.

If you compile with `-optimize`, the for loop version will likely be even faster, because `List.foreach` should be inlined, eliminating the cost of the lambda.

Comment: The `seq.size` is a bigger cost for `List`.

Comment: @sjrd shouldn't compilers be taking care of such mistakes?

Comment: Short answer: no, a compiler cannot save you from being in the entirely wrong complexity class! Long answer would deserve a full question on its own, and would not even fit the format of SO, I'm afraid (open ended, not a concrete programming problem, etc.).

Comment: @sjrd I meant `seq.size` is just one `O(n)` call. If the compiler is smart enough to factor this call out (which I believe should be happening if not already), the complexity of the code will remain `O(n)`.

Comment: No the complexity of the code will still be O(n^2) because `seq(i)` is O(n) itself. Moreover, the compiler does not know that `seq.size` will never change, so it cannot factor it out of the loop.